# When I try to upload an image with some additional data postman returns "Unexpected field","Bad Request" in nestjs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

**I am a self-learner. When I try to upload an image with some additional data postman returns this error... Has anyone any idea about this..?**

[image]

This is my controller method :

```
 @Post()
  @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('file'))
  async create(
    @UploadedFile() file: Express.Multer.File,
    @Body() createItemDto: CreateItemDto,
  ) {
    console.log('item', createItemDto);
    console.log('file', file);
    // try {
    //   const item = await this.itemService.create(createItemDto);
    //   return {
    //     statusCode: HttpStatus.OK,
    //     message: 'Item created successfully',
    //     item,
    //   };
    // } catch (error) {
    //   return {
    //     message: error.detail,
    //   };
    // }
  }
```

My DTO :
[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FileInterceptor('image')` instead of `FileInterceptor('file')`?

Comment: @Jay McDoniel Thank you sir...

Comment: how did you make postman handle the "true" values as booleans instead of strings?

Comment: @user15013406 I create custom validate function for this 

import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';

export function toBoolean(): (target: any, key: string) => void {
  return Transform(({ value }: any) => {
    return value === 'true' || value === true || value === 1 || value === '1';
  });
}

Comment: Thanks :) That pointed me to the right direction. Is it correct that I need to manually set transform: true in the global validation pipe to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `file` option passed to the `FileInterceptor` is incorrect according to the `postman` request. It should be `FileInterceptor('image')` not `FileInterceptor('file')`

Answer (score 0):

you should never ever directly write a DTO from the controller to the database.
If you're not using forbidNonWhitelisted in the global validation pipe, any data could be added to the DTO and potentially written to the database